# SQL запрос со вложенными операциями

Tags: sql, база-данных

Новичек в SQL, не до конца понимаю как всё это работает. Нужно вывести список магазинов из таблицы shops в которых пользователь 360767 совершил >= 7 транзакций. написал вот это

```
SELECT * FROM shops 
WHERE id = SELECT 'to' FROM transactions
WHERE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaction WHERE 'from' = '360767') >= 7);
```

Не понимаю как получить id магазинов у которых покупок больше 7
Вот сама бд: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uYKJnQrug681Xzxn_qpILzeP6Kdvolll

Comment: таблички то огромные, вот онлайн бдшик http://sqliteviewer.flowsoft7.com

Comment: скриптов нет, это данные мне исходники

Comment: Почитайте про `group by` и `having`. Текущий запрос вернет вообще все строки, если конечно не даст синтаксических ошибок. Так же обратите внимание, что имена колонок ни в одной БД не заключаются в одинарные кавычки.

Comment: Надо 1) Отобрать транзакции только нужного пользователя (WHERE) 2) Сгруппировать по магазину (GROUP BY) 3) Посчитать количество записей для каждого магазина (COUNT) 4) Отобрать нужные (HAVING).

Answer (score 1):

> как получить id магазинов у которых покупок больше 7

Нужно использовать `GROUP BY` и `HAVING` (это как `WHERE`, но по результату группировки)

```
SELECT to
FROM transaction
WHERE from = '360767'
GROUP BY to
HAVING COUNT(*) => 7
```

> Нужно вывести список магазинов из таблицы shops в которых...

В данном случае можно использовать IN

```
SELECT * FROM shops 
WHERE id IN (указанный выше запрос)
```